# Is it possible to get a route parameter in lumen with a domain url?

Tags: php, routes, dns, lumen

I'm trying to make a route in lumen that receives a domain as a parameter

`$route->get('/websites/website/{domain}', ['uses' => 'WebsiteController@show', 'as' => 'website-show']);`

But if I try to run localhost:8000/websites/website/mywebsite.com I get the following message:

**Not Found**
*The requested resource /websites/website/mywebsite.com was not found on this server.*

Why is this? I tried to find an explanation but couldn't.

Thanks in advance.